# from python 32 bits to python 64 bits

Tags: python, 64-bit, 32-bit, anaconda, pythonxy

I have some doubts about how to do that, I hope anybody can point me in the correct direction.

My current situation is that I am working with the python package Python(x,y) 32 bits in a Windows machine with 64 bits. And, as many of you know, I am having some problems with the `Memory error`.

So that I am thinking about changing to 64-bits, let's say with Anaconda for example.

My concern is about what can happen with all the previous job done with python 2.7 with 32 bits. Will it work with Anaconda 64?.

And, if finally I change to Anaconda 64, I really don't think I can still use QtDesigner anymore, if I am not wrong, it only works with python 32, right?.

Sorry If any question sound very basic, I really do not have any idea about that.

Comment: why do you think  QtDesigner won't work?

Comment: Because of the PyQt4 package?? but as I said I am not sure at all....have no idea

Comment: There are 64 bit binaries that should not be any problem. http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

Comment: That is a very good starting point, thanks!

Comment: I don't think changing your python to 64 bit will break anything either, maybe the other way around could cause issues but I cannot see any obvious reason why it would cause you any problems. You can of course use both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reinstall everything for the 64-bit Python, but note that Anaconda and conda may already come with everything that you need.

Comment: ok thanks! then I have a big question: Now I am currently working with Python(x,y) 32, so, what if I install Anaconda 64, but keeping python(x,y) 32?? Will it be a mess or both of then can be installed on time?...For me the most important is that the the old things in python 32 don't stop working.

Comment: The two will be separate. You should make sure you don't have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set. The only thing that will affect which one gets used is what is in your PATH environment variable (the Anaconda installer puts Anaconda in the PATH automatically).